# How to build a data frame from several xls files?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, xls

I am trying to build a data frame from several xls tables I downloaded:

```
states <- c("A","B","C","D")

for(i in states){
download.file(paste("http://www.web.com/state=",i,".xyz",sep=""),paste("temp",i,".xls",sep=""),mode = "wb")              
    }
```

Which works fine. But what I am having trouble is that I want to build a data frame with all these excel files (which I have no trouble reading individually using `gdata`'s `read.xls`) AND I need to insert a column on the data frame which tells me where the data comes from, i.e. from A, B, C , or D.

For example, I insert these in the loop

```
state <- read.xls(paste("temp",i,".xls",sep=""),sheet=1, header = F, skip = 1, perl="C:/Perl/perl/bin/perl.exe",row.names=NULL)
    state$UF <- data.frame(state,paste(i,sep=""))
```

It works OK, but I don't know what to do after this step (or if I can make it simpler). What I had in mind to do next was to rename `state` into `stateA, stateB`, etc. within the loop but I don't know how to do that. After renaming the individual data frames, I would use `rbind` to set them together.

Do you  have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gdata's `read.xls` can download and read a file off the internet all in one `read.xls` call:

```
urls <- sprintf("http://www.web.com/state=%s.xyz", states)
L <- lapply(urls, read.xls, ...other.read.xls.arguments...)
names(L) <- states
```

The above produces a list, `L`, of data frames.  If all the data frames are of the same form then the list can be combined into a single data frame, `DF`, like this:

```
DF <- do.call(rbind, L)
```

The row names of `DF` will indicate which state each row came from.  Optionally a new column could be added like this (where the `sub` removes the row number portion of the row names):

```
DF$state <- sub("\\.\\d*$", "", rownames(DF))
rownames(DF) <- NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

The general strategy that works well in R is to load your stuff into a list:

```
state_list = lapply(list.files(pattern = "xls"), read.xls, sheet = 1, etc)
big_df = do.call("rbind", state_list)
```

or even shorter using `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
big_df = ldply(list.files(pattern = "xls"), read.xls, sheet = 1, etc)
```

Notice that there is no explicite `for` loop here, and that the code is very short and to the point.

Comment: Hmmm, I had tried that actually, but I get an error: `Error in xls2sep(xls, sheet, verbose = verbose, ..., method = method,  : 
  Intermediate file 'C:\Users\temp\fileb00852605506.csv' missing!
In addition: Warning message: running command '"C:\Perl\perl\bin\perl.exe" "C:/Users/.../R/win-library/2.15/gdata/perl/xls2csv.pl"  "tempCE.xls" "C:\Users\temp\fileb00852605506.csv" "1"' had status 255 
Error in file.exists(tfn) : invalid 'file' argument`

Comment: Please create a reproducible example which reproduces your problem on our computer.